# Xen and Networking

Tags: networking, xen

I'm using Xen 4.1

I have a (debian) host with 1 ethernet adapter on 172.16.1.0/24 range, static configuration.

I want to have **various** (centOS) guests, that will be on a different network: 192.168.0.0/16, static configuration.

What's the best solution for this? I also want the other hosts on 172.16.1.0/24 to access the 192.168.0.0/16 network trough the host IP.

I want to avoid NAT, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well...you could do just that.

Give the DomUs all static IPs and be done with it.

You'd then want to have Dom0 act as a gateway router and update everyone's routing table on the 172.16.1.0/24 to talk to go to Dom0 if they want to access 192.168.0.0/16.

This is a messy question and a messy solution.

Your wanting to put two separate networks on the same network segment.

I don't recommend it.